# Problema ao exibir array

Tags: php, array, lógica

Estou com um problema na lógica para exibir os dados de um array.

É o seguinte:

Tenho uma função, que me retorna o resultado de cadastros por UF por dia. Nela passo 2 parâmetros, um array com as datas e um array com os estados.

Montando os parametros para passar para a funçao.

```
$uf = array('sp','rj');

$d1 = '2015-09-15';
$d2 = '2015-09-17';
$timestamp1 = strtotime( $d1 );
$timestamp2 = strtotime( $d2 );

while ( $timestamp1 <= $timestamp2 ) {
   $data_mod[] = date( 'Y-m-d', $timestamp1 ) . PHP_EOL; // data_mod vira um array com as data entre $d1 e $d2
   $timestamp1 += 86400;
}
```

Função:

```
function grafico_cadastro_por_dia($conexao,$uf,$data_mod){
$lista = array();
$qtd_dias = count($data_mod);
$qtd_uf = count($uf);

for($i = 0; $i <= $qtd_uf; $i++) {
if( $uf[$i] ) {  $where[] = " uf = '{$uf[$i]}'"; } //monto o implode para o array de UF
}

for($i = 0; $i <= $qtd_dias; $i++) {
if( $data_mod[$i] ) {  $where2[] = " dataCadastro = '{$data_mod[$i]}'"; } //monto o implode para o array de datas
} 

$query = "SELECT dataCadastro,uf,sum(cadastros) FROM tblCadastros where (".implode( ' or ',$where2 ).") AND (".implode( ' or ',$where ).") group by 1,2";
   $sql = mysql_query($query,$conexao);
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){
   $lista[] = $row;
 } 
return $lista;
}
```

No retorno da função, eu recebo os seguintes dados.

```
$funcao = grafico_cadastro_por_dia($conexao,$uf,$data_mod);

for($i = 0; $i <= count($funcao); $i++){
  echo  '<br>';
 print_r($funcao[$i]);
}

Resultado: 

Array ( [dataCadastro] => 2015-09-15 [uf] => SP [sum(cadastros)] => 36 )
Array ( [dataCadastro] => 2015-09-15 [uf] => RJ [sum(cadastros)] => 9 )
Array ( [dataCadastro] => 2015-09-16 [uf] => SP [sum(cadastros)] => 19 )
Array ( [dataCadastro] => 2015-09-16 [uf] => RJ [sum(cadastros)] => 8 )
Array ( [dataCadastro] => 2015-09-17 [uf] => SP [sum(cadastros)] => 14 )
Array ( [dataCadastro] => 2015-09-17 [uf] => rj [sum(cadastros)] => 2 )
```

Como podem ver  , a função retorna 2 vezes a data pois tem mais de um estado para exibir o valor.

Se eu passo 3 estados no array , ele exibiria 3 vezes a mesma data.

***Até ai, tudo bem.***

O problema começa agora , já que vou colocar esses resultados em um gráfico.

E não estou conseguindo imprimir os resultados na ordem que o gráfico pede.

Teria que exibir nessa ordem:

```
[$data, $total "uf SP" , $total "uf RJ"]
['2015-09-15', 36 , 9],// 36 é o valor de cadastro de SP no dia 15 e 9 o valor de cadastros de RJ no dia 15
['2015-09-16', 19 , 8],
```

e assim por diante.

Mas já rascunhei de tudo quanto é forma que consegui imaginar, mas não consegui exibir os dados dessa forma.

Alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Henrique, eu re-li umas 3 vezes, me desculpe. Talvez seja o cansaço mas não consegui absorver sua dúvida. Eu entendi referente a estrutura da array mas não entendi como deve ser o output. Por favor entente colocar mais códigos, você apenas disse a estrutura da array mas acredito estar faltando pouco de código, e seja especifico no output que deseja. Bom, me desculpe novamente.

Comment: Estas datas vem do banco de dados? Ou simplesmente de um array()?

Comment: Como estou testando em local host , estou definindo as datas manualmente , mas quando passar para o servidor receberei elas via POST. @juniorb2ss , então , o resto do código seria minha função que  pega os dados no banco.

Comment: Dando um print_r na funcao , ele retorna assim : Array ( [0] => Array ( [dataCadastro] => 2015-09-15 [uf] => SP [sum(total)] => 36 ) [1] => Array ( [dataCadastro] => 2015-09-15 [uf] => RJ [sum(total)] => 9 ) [2] => Array ( [dataCadastro] => 2015-09-16 [uf] => SP [sum(total)] => 19 ) [3] => Array ( [dataCadastro] => 2015-09-16 [uf] => RJ [sum(total)] => 8 ) [4] => Array ( [dataCadastro] => 2015-09-17 [uf] => SP [sum(total)] => 14 ) [5] => Array ( [dataCadastro] => 2015-09-17 [uf] => rj [sum(total)] => 2 ) ).

Comment: Amigo, tem má formatação desse seu array. Ele esta formatado incorreto, vou tentar postar uma resposta.

Comment: Qual biblioteca para gerar gráfico você está tentando usar? Tem algum exemplo online? Para facilitar a leitura, você poderia trabalhar com uma matriz aninhada por interesse, EX: ['2015-09-15' => ['SP' => 10, 'RJ' => 15], '2015-09-16' => ['SP' => 3, 'RJ' => 11]]

Comment: Tem um problema na lógica mesmo. Acredito que a forma que você está fazendo não é muito indicada, outro detalhe, é que você pode pegar pelo alias: `sum(cadastros) as total_cadastros` : `$row["total_cadastros"]`. Esta saída que você está fazendo, dá pra fazer direto na query.

Comment: Boa tarde, uso o Google charts. Estou montando um grafico de linhas, para saber os dias que teve mais cadastros no site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você esta percorrendo muitos arrays para no final montar uma query para pegar os valores por data dos cadastros feitos naquele UF, sendo que próprio SQL da ferramentas para isso.

Temos a função [Between](https://talibamartins.wordpress.com/2007/09/20/comparacoes-no-mysql-between/) que é usada para comparações.

Neste exemplo irei mostrar como pegar todos os cadastros feitos entre um período de data e agrupar pela data do cadastro e uf.

Assim poderei retornar todos os cadastros feitos em x UF para Y dia, montando array que você precisa.

Nesta query irei utilizar o [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) do MySQL, pois vou partir do principio que seu campo `dataCadastro` tenha o horário do cadastro, se eu não formatar esta data irei agrupar os cadastros por `dia/mês/ano hora:minuto:segundo` que não é o que você precisa, você precisa apenas por `dia/mês/ano`.

Basta executar esta query invés desse código todo:

```
SELECT 
DATE_FORMAT(`dataCadastro`, '%Y-%m-%d') AS `dataCadastro`,
uf,
SUM(cadastros) AS 'Cadastros'
FROM
  tblCadastros
WHERE
  dataCadastro BETWEEN 2015 - 09 - 15 AND 2015 - 09 - 17
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(`dataCadastro`, '%Y-%m-%d'), `uf`
```

Execute apenas esta query invés deste código todo que você fez. O resultado dessa você poderá montar um array dinâmico mais ou menos assim:

```
Array
(
    [2015-09-15] => Array
    (
        [SP] => 36
        [RJ] => 9
    )
)
```

[Veja no ideone](https://ideone.com/xiJ1eH)

Como ficaria final:

```
$query = 'SELECT DATE_FORMAT(`dataCadastro`, "%Y%m%d") as `dataCadastro`, uf, sum(cadastros) as Cadastros FROM tblCadastros where dataCadastro BETWEEN '. $d1 .' and '. $d2 .' GROUP BY `dataCadastro`, `uf`';
$sql = mysql_query($query,$conexao);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
    $lista[$row['dataCadastro']] = [
        $row['uf'] => $row['Cadastros']
    ];
}
```

Dúvidas? Viu como reduziu todo esse seu código?

Dessa forma você tem um array montado com as informações que deseja para montar o gráfico, ai é só percorrer ele.

## Edit

```
$lista = array();

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql))
{
   if(!isset($lista[$row['dataCadastro']]))
   {
    $lista[$row['dataCadastro']] = array(
        $row['uf'] => $row['Cadastros']
    );
   }
   else
   {
      $lista[$row['dataCadastro']] += array(
        $row['uf'] => $row['Cadastros']
      );
   }
}
```

[Veja em funcionamento](https://ideone.com/oDRz5o)

Comment: Obrigado pelo ajuda . Mas , deu o seguinte erro : Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '[' in F:\PROGRAMAS INSTALADOS\Ampps\www\testes\teste_loop\loop_data_uf\index.php on line 63. Conteudo da linha 63 :  $lista[$row['dataCadastro']] = [
        $row['uf'] => $row['Cadastros']
    ];  Desde ja , grato

Comment: Henrique, isso é erro de sintaxe. É só corrigir amigo. Qual versão do seu PHP? Não é suportado abrir array assim `[]` onde tiver você terá que trocar por `array()`

Comment: junior , mais uma vez obrigado pela ajuda.Esta na versao 5.3 se nao me engano .Tentei dessa forma : $lista = array("data_cadastro" => $row['dataCadastro'],"dados" => array( "uf" => $row['uf'],"cadastros" => $row['cadastros'])); . Mas ao dar um print_r no retorno , ele só mostrou uma linha.

Comment: Pois você esta sobrescrevendo o array, Henrique. Veja minha resposta atualizada.

Comment: @HenriqueFelix veja a edição da resposta.

Comment: quase . Deu essa saida : Array ( [2015-09-15] => Array ( [SP] => 36 ) [2015-09-16] => Array ( [SP] => 19 ) [2015-09-17] => Array ( [SP] => 14 ) ) . No caso , não pegou o outro estado .

Comment: Henrique, por favor analise o código. Também não podemos dar de mão beijada. Por favor sinalize a resposta como correta e positive, com pequenos ajustes você faz o array que precisa.

Comment: Junior , deu certo. Não tinha visto seu ultimo Edit. Retorno: Array ( [2015-09-15] => Array ( [RJ] => 9 [SP] => 36 ). Muito obrigado pela paciencia e pela ajuda.

Comment: O importante não é só funcionar, é estudar a query, olha a diferença entre executar uma query do que 30 linhas de códigos que era o seu código, estude as funções utilizada, @HenriqueFelix

Comment: Eu reparei. O que pesou foi na hora de comparar a data , não sei o porque fiz daquele jeito, sendo que o betwen resolveria ,tornando o cod mais correto.Agora, vou dar uma estuda mais profunda nos array, pois me perdi um pouco de como fez. Mais uma vez , grato.